# Image will not replace text in email body unless email is displayed, why?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, ms-word

I have a report that I send out daily. In it there is a linked image to a range that I need to paste into an email and send. I have the email saved as an outlook template file that I modify as necessary when I need to.

The code I have runs from Excel.
I create an Outlook object and open the Outlook email from the `.oft` template file. Then I want to find the identifier text (`*INSERT IMAGE HERE*`) and replace it with the linked image from Excel, which has been copied from the clipboard. I am trying to add it as an InLineShape so that it behaves properly in the body of the email. Thanks to another question I have asked, I can replace the text properly, paste the image inline as I wanted and resize it but something strange has started happening.

When I run my macro as is, the text is not replaced and the image is not added. When I step through it and add a quick `.Display` line for troubleshooting, the image is displayed. I would like to avoid having to display the email before I send it just for efficiency purposes. I don't understand how or why this is happening.

Here is a quick sample of my code:

```
Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutlookEmail = OutlookApp.CreateItemFromTemplate(templatePath)

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Email Sheet").Pictures("Summary Email Screenshot").Copy 

Set EmailWordEditor = OutlookEmail.GetInspector.WordEditor 
Set EmailText = EmailWordEditor.Content 

With EmailText.Find 'Using the .Find method to find the text identifier
    .ClearFormatting
    .text = "*INSERT IMAGE HERE*" 
    .MatchCase = True 
    .MatchWildcards = False 
    If .Execute Then 'If found, delete text, paste image
        EmailText.Delete 
        EmailText.PasteSpecial Placement:=wdInLine 
    End If
End With

EmailWordEditor.InlineShapes(EmailWordEditor.InlineShapes.count).ScaleHeight = 75 
'OutlookEmail.Display 'With this uncommented, the image is loaded properly
OutlookEmail.Send 

Set OutlookApp = Nothing 'Unload the objects properly
Set OutlookEmail = Nothing
```

I am pretty well versed in Excel VBA, but this is my first attempt at Outlook and Word VBA so please, bear with me.

EDIT 11/30/18

I have looked into the problem more and have learned that in doing a `.Display`, Excel evokes certain checks to validate the data in the email. From a comment on another post to stack overflow by Dmitry Streblechenko:

> When you touch Outlook inspector (through Display, Close, GetInspector), Outlook runs extra code that validates your data. You got lucky it was smart enough to fix your attachment. If you do not want to rely on that, set the PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID property explicitly - that is how Outlook knows which attachment must be used for a particular img tag.

I do not want to touch the email body with HTML as there is content in the template that changes on a weekly basis before the `*INSERT IMAGE HERE*` identifier. If I was building the email from scratch, the HTML route would probably be easier, but I chose the `.WordEditor` route to specifically circumvent this issue. I also do not know how to code in HTML at all, so it would be more difficult for me to try to solve this problem with it. Is there any way I can manually validate the content of the email body without having to use `.Display` to make Outlook do it?

Comment: Have you tried to call Save before calling Send?

Comment: I just tried it and it and sent it to myself without stepping through the code and it sent it to me without the image. I changed the line to `OutlookEmail.Display` and ran it without stepping through and it sent it with the image. I still do not understand why and I would prefer not to display the email before sending since it slows things down and shows things to the user that I would rather not show.

Comment: You only other option is save the image as a file, add it as an attachment, set PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID property on the attachment using Attachment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty, and create HTML body that references that image through the cid attribute in the img tag.

Comment: I have come across this approach in trying to solve this issue, but I do not want to go the HTML route. The reason why is because there is a lot of content in this email that is subject to change before the identifier text `*INSERT IMAGE HERE*`. If I was building the email from scratch, I think it would be easier, but I chose the `WordEditor` route specifically to circumvent this. It is also the reason why I use a template file to create the object. Is there no way to evoke Outlook to "refresh" email content for lack of a better term?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko I updated my question based on the solution you gave to another user's question. You think there's a way to do it without HTML? Or is there a way to do it with HTML after I replace the text with the `WordEditor`?

Comment: No, you have to do that using HTML. You are free to have a template and just replace the relevant substring there based on the actual file attachment.

Comment: Do you think you can show me an example of how to search for my string and replace it with the image? Like I said before, I don't know how to code in HTML so this would be really helpful for me to get started.

Comment: See https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/733bbc4f-2bdc-4d73-83c1-9a46585859bf/outlook-2010-create-a-message-from-an-htm-file?forum=outlookdev